# Hacer click en boton al presionar la tecla enter dentro de un textbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un TexBox y un Button. Quiero que cuando el foco esté en el textbox y al presionar la tecla enter se haga click automaticamente en el boton.

Actualmente tengo este código, pero lo que hace es simplemente cambiar el foco desde el textbox al button, lo cual obliga igualmente a hacer click en el boton. Además genera un pitido (no deseado) al presionar la tecla enter. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

```
private void cambiarFoco_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: y si llamas al evento click del boton?

Comment: Si funciona. Pero como quito el sonido al presionar enter?

Comment: la tecla enter no hace ningun sonido. y winforms no agrega sonidos porque si. Sera algo de tu pc o de algun otro lado? que tipo de sonido hace?

Comment: Es el mismo sonido de cuando se quiere expulsar un pendrive y windows no deja porque está en uso.

Comment: parece ser algo de esa pc. .net no agrega sonidos a ningun sistema, el que se ocupa de los sonidos del sistema es windows. Lo probaste en otro lado? seguro no hay ningun sonido...

Comment: Lo probé en varios equipos, con distinta version de windows y también tiene el sonido al presionar enter.

Comment: podrias hacer un [mcve] para que probemos todos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solución a mi problema, la escribo por si a alguien más le sirve.
La encontré aquí [link](https://alexjimenez.wordpress.com/2008/01/25/truco-pasar-entre-textbox-con-la-tecla-enter-vb-y-csharp-windows-forms/).
Para que se entienda mejor el nombre de mi Textbox es "txtBuscar" y el botón "btnBuscar".

```
private void txtBuscar_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Enter))
        {
            e.Handled = true;//elimina el sonido
            btnBuscar_Click(sender, e);//llama al evento click del boton
        }
    }
```